# how can we encrypt our password while logging into sqlplus

Tags: database, security, oracle11g, database-administration

I want to log in sqlplus(oracle) via command prompt windows but how can i log in without my password being visible.for eg: sqlplus -s TEST/*****
or conn TEST/***** where now if i provide this they are visible to the user who is typing.Is there any method in Oracle 11g so that we can hide the password of user who os loggin in.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the password as part of the connect string - it will prompt you for it and then it will not be visible. example: sqlplus user@service. these may help as well:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_hide_oracle_password_sql_plus_sql_loader.htm
http://www.kieranoshea.com/2013/04/28/hide-sqlplus-password-string/
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:142212348066

Comment: suppose i have fetched like this     a=`awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /home/oracle/sumeet/file.txt` in file .txt there is a password and now i want to connect like this sqlplus -s "MDR_113/$a@tns entry will this work???